# R: Using different DFs to get third DF with specific info from first 2

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I have two data frames, `df1` has information about a publication's year, outlet name, total articles in this publication in a year, and a cumulative sum of articles over the period of time I'm studying. `df2` has a random sample of article IDs, with potential values ranging from 1 to the total number of articles given by `df1$cumsum`.

What I need to do is to grab each article ID in `df2` and identify in which publication and year it falls under, using the information contained in `df1`.

Here's a minimally reproducible example:

```
set.seed(890)
df1 <- NULL
df1$year <- c(2000:2009, 2000:2009)
df1$outlet <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2)
df1$article_total <- sample(1:200, 20, replace = T)
df1$cumsum <- cumsum(df1$article_total)
df1 <- as.data.frame(df1)

df2 <- NULL
df2$art_num <- sample(1:2102, 100, replace = T) # get random sample of article IDs for the total number of articles I have in this db
df2 <- as.data.frame(df2)
```

Ideally, I would also like to calculate an article's ID in each year. For example, in the data above, outlet 1 has 14 articles in the year 2000 and 168 in 2001 (cumsum = 183). If I have an article ID of 156, I would like to know that it is the 142th article in the year 2001 of publication 1. And so on and so forth for every article ID I have in this database.

I was thinking I should do this with a `for` loop, but I'm 100% lost in writing it. Here's what I began writing, but I have a feeling I'm not on the right track with it:

```
for i in 1:nrow(df2$art_num){
  article_number <- df2$art_num[i]
  if (article_number %in% df1$cumsum){ # note: cumsum should be an interval before doing this?
    # get article number, year, publication in new df
    # also calculate article ID in each year/publication
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help! I'm still lost with writing loops in R...

**#######################
EDITED EXAMPLE as per Frank's suggestion**

```
set.seed(890)
df1 <- NULL
df1$year <- c(2000:2002, 2000:2002)
df1$outlet <- c(1, 1, 1, 2,2,2)
df1$article_total <- sample(1:50, 6, replace = T)
df1$cumsum <- cumsum(df1$article_total)
df1 <- as.data.frame(df1)

df2 <- NULL
df2$art_id <- c(66, 120, 77, 156, 24)
df2 <- as.data.frame(df2)
```

Here's the output I'm looking for:

```
  art_id outlet year article_number
1     66      1 2002             19
2    120      2 2000             35
3     77      1 2002             30
4    156      2 2001             35
5     24      1 2000             20
```

This example shows my ideal output in `df3`, which I calculated/built by hand. It has one column with the article's ID, the appropriate outlet, the year, and a new variable `art_number`. This is different than the article ID in that I calculated it from `df1$cumsum` and `df3$art_id`. In this example, the first row shows that the first article in my database has an ID of 66. I obtain a `art_number` value of 19 because this article (id = 66) is the 19th article published in the year 2002 by outlet 1. I calculated this value by looking at the article ID, locating the year and outlet based on the `df1$cumsum`, and then substracting the `art_id` value from the `df1$cumsum` value for the previous year. So for this specific article, I calculated `df3$art_number = df3$art_id[1,1] - df1$cumsum[2,4]`

I need to do this calculation for every article in my data base so I don't do this process by hand forever.

Comment: @Frank my desired output is a third df that contains the following columns: `df2$art_num`, `df1$outlet` (based on the article number of df2), df1$year` (based on the article number of df2), and, ideally, `df3$article_location`. This third one is based on `df2$art_num` and`df1$cumsum`,. I don't have a reproducible example of exactly what I want because I can't write code to show what I need... Ideally, cumsum would be an interval instead of straight up numbers so that I can locate the specific article IDs within it. I'm not sure I make sense, so let me know if I can clarify anything further.

Comment: @Frank included a new output you can see... Hope that's helpful!

Comment: @Frank you're right, I had not set the seed for the sampling of `df2`. Wrote it out by hand instead.

Comment: It is sounding to me like you want some variant of Python's [`bisect.insort` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html). There is a nice explanation [here in the book Fluent Python](https://books.google.com/books?id=kYZHCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA50&lpg=PA50&dq=python+insort+example&source=bl&ots=isuiUrDLIi&sig=HEErrz0JgexeTPGUq1Sj8yGeaYE&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjcy6morKXWAhXGyoMKHfIpBi8Q6AEIVzAI#v=onepage&q=python%20insort%20example&f=false). I think in this case you are just looking to preserve the indices of the insertion order, though, right? Not sure if there's a native R version of this.

Comment: Or at least some R version of Python's `insort` would be a component of reaching the answer you describe. You might also want to take a step back and see if this is really the easiest way to approach the greater problem you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your data structure makes sense, though it would be easier with one additional column, for the first article in a year and outlet:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1); setDT(df2)

df1[, art_cstart := shift(cumsum(article_total), fill=0L) + 1L]

   year outlet article_total cumsum art_cstart
1: 2000      1             4      4          1
2: 2001      1            43     47          5
3: 2002      1            38     85         48
4: 2000      2            36    121         86
5: 2001      2            39    160        122
6: 2002      2             8    168        161
```

Now, we can do a rolling update join, "rolling" each `art_id` to the previous `cumsum` and computing each desired column:

```
df2[, c("outlet", "year", "art_num") := df1[df2, on=.(cumsum = art_id), roll=-Inf, .(
  x.year,
  x.outlet,
  i.art_id - x.art_cstart + 1L
)]]

   art_id outlet year art_num
1:     66   2002    1      19
2:    120   2000    2      35
3:     77   2002    1      30
4:    156   2001    2      35
5:     24   2001    1      20
```

---

*How it works*

- `x[i, on=, roll=, j]` is the syntax for a join, looking up each row of `i` in `x`.
- In this join `j` evaluates to a list of columns, `.(...)` shorthand for `list(...)`.
- Column assignment is done with `(colnames) := .(...)`.

The assignment is to the existing table `df2` instead of unnecessarily creating a new table.

For details on how data.table syntax works, see the startup messages...

```
> library(data.table)
data.table 1.10.4
  The fastest way to learn (by data.table authors): https://www.datacamp.com/courses/data-analysis-the-data-table-way
  Documentation: ?data.table, example(data.table) and browseVignettes("data.table")
  Release notes, videos and slides: http://r-datatable.com
```

Comment: I can't upvote this enough. This code did exactly what I needed to, Frank. Thank you SO much! I'll definitely take a look at `data.table`!

Answer (score 0):

This is the code you need I think:

```
df3 <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 3, nrow = 0))
colnames(df3) <- c("articleNumber", "year", "publication")
for(i in 1:nrow(df2$art_num)){
 for(j in 1:nrow(df1$cumsum)) {
  if ((df2$art_num[i] >= df1$cumsum[j]) && (df2$art_num[i] <= df1$cumsum[j + 1])){ 
    # note: cumsum should be an interval before doing this? NOT REALLY SURE 
    # WHAT YOU NEED HERE
    # get article number, year, publication in new df
    df3[i, 1] <- df2$art_num[i]
    df3[i, 2] <- df1$year[j]
    df3[i, 3] <- df1$outlet[j]
    # also calculate article ID in each year/publication ISN'T THIS 
    # art_num?
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for this, I updated the example in the original question to show exactly what I need to obtain...